# Wordpress display category posts on different page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a posts category setup called Portfolio. Currently the URL is www.example.com/category/portfolio, how would I display the same page but the url be www.example.com/portfolio?

Maybe I can create a new Template for that page, but how would I display the same results? I was thinking about there might be a URL alias setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a template for this is a solution, but I think it will only work efficiently if you have small number of categories.

Try using:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/top-level-cats/

I think there are other available plugins to do this.